# crypto_secretbox_easy appends several '[NUL]' characters to the end of text

Tags: c, macos, cryptography, libsodium

I have created two functions 'encryptf', and 'decrytpf' (named with 'f' to avoid naming conflict with pre-existing libsodium functions. These functions are pretty self explanatory, they encrypt, and decrypt a given input string using a provided key.

The following is the encryption method. It should be noted that the 'key' is simple a randomly generated string of ANSI characters.

```c
int encryptf(const char *input_file, const char *output_file, const unsigned char *key) {  
    if (sodium_init() < 0) {  
        printf("Error initializing\n");  
        return 1;  
    }  
  
    // Get input and output files and ensure read/write, creation if needed.  
  FILE *input = fopen(input_file, "r");  
    FILE *output = fopen(output_file, "ab+");  
    if (!input || !output) {  
        printf("Error opening files to encrypt\n");  
        return 1;  
    }  
  
    // Get file size  
  fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);  
    size_t file_size = ftell(input);  
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_SET);  
  
    // Allocate memory for plaintext and ciphertext  
  unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *) malloc(file_size);  
    unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char *) malloc(file_size + crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES);  
  
    // Create nonce char array, and populate it with secure randombytes from libsodium library  
  unsigned char nonce[crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES];  
    randombytes(nonce, sizeof(nonce));  
  
    // Read plaintext from file  
  fread(plaintext, 1, file_size, input);  
  
    // Create 'mac' array to get rid of authentication tag.  
  unsigned char mac[crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES];  
  
    // Encrypt plaintext  
  crypto_secretbox_easy(ciphertext, plaintext, file_size, nonce, key);  
  
    // Write nonce and ciphertext to output file  
  fwrite(nonce, 1, sizeof(nonce), output);  
    fwrite(ciphertext, 1, file_size + crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES, output);  
  
    // Cleanup  
  fclose(input);  
    fclose(output);  
    free(plaintext);  
    free(ciphertext);  
  
    return 0;  
}
```

And the decryption function:

```c
int decryptf(const char *input_file, const char *output_file, const unsigned char *key) {  
    if (sodium_init() < 0) {  
        printf("Error initializing Libsodium\n");  
        return 1;  
    }  
  
    FILE *input = fopen(input_file, "rb");  
    FILE *output = fopen(output_file, "wb");  
    if (!input || !output) {  
        printf("Error opening files to decrypt\n");  
        return 1;  
    }  
  
    // Read nonce from file  
  unsigned char nonce[crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES];  
    fread(nonce, 1, sizeof(nonce), input);  
  
    // Get file size excluding nonce  
  fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);  
    size_t file_size = ftell(input) - crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES;  
    fseek(input, crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES, SEEK_SET);  
  
    // Allocate memory for ciphertext and plaintext  
  unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char *) malloc(file_size);  
    unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *) malloc(file_size);  
  
    // Read ciphertext from file  
  fread(ciphertext, 1, file_size, input);  
  
    // Decrypt ciphertext  
  if (crypto_secretbox_open_easy(plaintext, ciphertext, file_size, nonce, key) != 0) {  
        printf("Error decrypting %s\n", input_file);  
        return 1;  
    }  
  
    // Write plaintext to output file  
  fwrite(plaintext, 1, file_size, output);  
  
    // Cleanup  
  fclose(input);  
    fclose(output);  
    free(ciphertext);  
    free(plaintext);  
  
    return 0;  
}
```

What follows is a basic example of how I am running these functions. This is not my exact code, but is an ample representation of how I am using these functions without exposing my codebase:

```c
int main(void) {
    FILE *f1 = fopen("tests/file.txt", "ab+");  
  
    if (!f1 || !f2) {  
        printf("Failed create test files.\n");  
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);  
    }  
    fprintf(f1, "HELLO\n\nworld!\n..\n\thello\n../14hf\n1");  
    fclose(f1); 

    char *key = rand_string(32);
    encryptf("tests/file.txt", "tests/file_enc.txt", key);
        printf("File encrypted.\n");

        decryptf("tests/file_enc.txt", "tests/file.txt", fkey);
}
```

This does decrypt the contents of the file, but also appends the following strange characters to the end:

[Strange characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbj1A.png)

(I am aware stack overflow is not fond of images, but it seems as though my keyboard cannot copy them, or cannot display them, as copy/pasting them does nothing.)

I am sure it's important that these characters get removed, as I do not want to be leaving any trace, or way to decrypt, or gain any information about these files without the key, before or after encryption/decryption.

I have tried removing the authentication code provided by libsodium, as I was hoping that could be the issue, but it seems as though doing so ruins the file decryption process.

I'm not sure if it will be important, but I am running on a 2023 MacBook Pro with apple's M2 chip.

Thank you all for any help you can provide!

Comment: Regardless of anything else, if your file is larger than expected, you're passing the wrong size to `fwrite`.

Comment: During decryption, the same memory is allocated for the plaintext as for the ciphertext (`file_size`). However, the ciphertext (i.e. what `crypto_secretbox_easy()` returns) consists of the concatenation of the *actual* ciphertext and the 16 bytes MAC. As the plaintext length corresponds to the length of the actual ciphertext, 16 bytes too much memory are allocated for the plaintext. This is the reason for the surplus 16 bytes in your screenshot.

Comment: You can also easily recognize the bug by comparing the memory allocation during encryption and decryption. In the first case you have taken `crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES` into account, in the latter not.

Comment: @Topaco I also thought this was the issue, but subtracting crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES from file_size while allocating memory does not fix the bug.

Comment: Your fix is the logical consequence of the other one: If you only allocate `file_size - crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES` as memory for the plaintext during decryption, then it *obviously* only makes sense to write `file_size - crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES` bytes (and not `file_size` bytes).

Comment: @Topaco and yet you didn't tell me that, you told me I had too much memory allocated, not that I should subtract it from the file write sequence. If it was so *obvious* then maybe you should have said so! Could have resolved the issue, but instead I had to do so myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all those who might run into this same issue, I solved it by changing the way I used `fwrite`, from:

```c
fwrite(plaintext, 1, file_size, output);
```

to

```c
fwrite(plaintext, 1, file_size - crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES, output);
```

To account for the MAC authentication tag that `crypto_secretbox_easy` adds.

Comment: It would be more consistent if you also only allocate `file_size - crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES` bytes for the plaintext during decryption.

Comment: @Topaco As I have previously stated, that did not work. The characters still appeared. There was no way to subtract crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES from the allocation steps in order to fix this bug. It simply did not work, but this did.